# SSIS Package Failing during Job

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-job

I have a SSIS Package that run's fine locally but it is failing while I run it on a job with the following error

**Error Occured ..Please see the error Message :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

The code is below

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.CSharp;



        object missing = Missing.Value;
        public int Main()
        {

            //---------------------------  Declarations -----------------------//
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            string StrDBConnection = string.Empty;
            string LogFilePath = string.Empty;
            string strExcelDataOutPut = string.Empty;
            string sTempFile1 = string.Empty;
            string sTempFile2 = string.Empty;
            string sFilename = string.Empty;

            //---------------  Input Varaiables ---------------//

            LogFilePath = Dts.Variables["User::SSIS_DM_Log"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::CreateMonthlyJobPostingSummary_slogFile"].Value.ToString();
            strExcelDataOutPut = Dts.Variables["User::SSIS_DM_Output"].Value.ToString();
            LogFilePath = LogFilePath + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + ".log";
            sFilename = Dts.Variables["User::CreateMonthlyJobPostingSummary_sFileName"].Value.ToString();
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------//

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
            //---Create the FileSystem Object;

            try
            {
                sb.AppendLine("Formatting of Job posting summary file started..");
                FormatFile(strExcelDataOutPut + sFilename);
                sb.AppendLine("Formatting file method ended.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter outfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(LogFilePath))
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("Error Occured ..Please see the error Message :" + ex.Message);
                    outfile.Write(sb.ToString());
                }
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }

            return Dts.TaskResult;
        }


        #region format File
        public void FormatFile(string sFilename)
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objExcelWbk = default(Excel.Workbook);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objWrksheetSummary = default(Excel.Worksheet);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objWrksheetDetail = default(Excel.Worksheet);


            try
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(sFilename))
                {

                    int RowCount, RowCountS2, RowCountDetail;
                    int cStart = 6;
                    string RunYr = string.Empty, RunQtr = string.Empty;
                    string Value = string.Empty, PrintRow = string.Empty;
                    string Crangevalue = string.Empty, Crange2Value = string.Empty;
                    Excel.Range Crange, Crange1, Crange2;
                    string[] Arry;
                    objExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                    objExcelApp.Visible = false;
                    objExcelWbk = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilename, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, true);
                    objWrksheetSummary = (Excel.Worksheet)objExcelWbk.Worksheets["Summary"];
                    objWrksheetDetail = (Excel.Worksheet)objExcelWbk.Worksheets["Detail"];
                    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)objWrksheetSummary).Activate();
                    Crange = (Excel.Range)objWrksheetDetail.get_Range((object)"A2:A2", missing);
                    RunYr = (Crange.Value2 == null ? "" : Crange.Value2.ToString());
                    //RowCountS2 = objWrksheetSummary.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
                    //Issue Fix For Defect #335
                    Crange = (Excel.Range)objWrksheetSummary.Cells[1, 30];
                    Crange.Formula = "=COUNTA(a2:a20000)";
                    RowCountS2 = Convert.ToInt32(Crange.Value2.ToString());

                    Crange = (Excel.Range)objWrksheetSummary.Cells[1, 2];
                    Crange.Value2 = RunYr;
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'B', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'C', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'D', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'E', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'F', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'G', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'H', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'I', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'J', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'K', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'L', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'M', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");
                    RunFormat(ref objWrksheetSummary, 'N', RowCountS2 + 1, "Number");

                    Crange = (Excel.Range)objWrksheetSummary.get_Range((object)"A" + (RowCountS2 + 2).ToString() + (object)":A" + (RowCountS2 + 2).ToString(), missing);
                    Crange.Value2 = "Grand Total";
                    Crange = (Excel.Range)objWrksheetSummary.get_Range((object)"B" + (RowCountS2 + 2).ToString() + (object)":B" + (RowCountS2 + 2).ToString(), missing);
                    Crange.Formula = "=sum(B2:B" + (RowCountS2 + 1).ToString() + ")";
                    Crange.Copy(missing);
                    Crange1 = (Excel.Range)objWrksheetSummary.get_Range((object)"C" + (RowCountS2 + 2).ToString() + (object)":N" + (RowCountS2 + 2).ToString(), missing);
                    Crange1.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormulas, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, missing, missing);

                    Crange1 = (Excel.Range)objWrksheetSummary.get_Range((object)"A" + (RowCountS2 + 2).ToString() +(object) ":N" + (RowCountS2 + 2).ToString(), missing);
                    Crange1.Font.FontStyle = "Bold";

                    PrintRow = "A1:N" + (RowCountS2 + 2).ToString();
                    objWrksheetSummary.PageSetup.PrintArea = PrintRow;

                    // Start - Issue fix: Focus cursor to top of the sheet
                    Crange1 = (Excel.Range)objWrksheetSummary.Cells.get_Range((object)"A1", (object)"A1");
                    Crange1.Select();
                    // End - Issue fix: Focus cursor to top of the sheet

                    objExcelWbk.Save();

                    objExcelWbk.Close(true, missing, missing);
                    objExcelApp.Quit();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objExcelWbk);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objExcelApp);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objExcelWbk);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objExcelApp);
                System.GC.Collect();

            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Run Format
        public void RunFormat(ref Excel.Worksheet objWrksheet, char sColumn, int row, string Formattype)
        {
            int iNextCol = System.Convert.ToInt32(sColumn) + 1 - 64;
            Excel.Range CRange, Crange1, Crange2;
            CRange = (Excel.Range)objWrksheet.Columns[iNextCol, Missing.Value];
            CRange.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, Missing.Value);

            CRange = (Excel.Range)objWrksheet.Cells[2, iNextCol];

            switch (Formattype)
            {
                case "Date":
                    CRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>\"\"\"\",DATEVALUE(RC[-1]),\"\"\"\")";
                    break;
                case "Number":
                    CRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>\"\"\"\",RC[-1]*1,\"\"\"\")";
                    break;
            }
            if (row > 2)
            {

                Crange2 = (Excel.Range)objWrksheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)objWrksheet.Cells[2, iNextCol], (Excel.Range)objWrksheet.Cells[row, iNextCol]);
                CRange.AutoFill(Crange2, Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillDefault);
            }

            CRange = (Excel.Range)objWrksheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)objWrksheet.Cells[2, iNextCol], (Excel.Range)objWrksheet.Cells[row, iNextCol]);
            CRange.Copy(Missing.Value);

            Crange1 = (Excel.Range)objWrksheet.get_Range((object)sColumn + "2:" + (object)sColumn + (object)row.ToString(), missing);
            Crange1.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
            Crange1 = (Excel.Range)objWrksheet.Columns[iNextCol, Missing.Value];
            Crange1.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft);

            Crange1 = (Excel.Range)objWrksheet.get_Range((object)sColumn + "2:" + (object)sColumn + (object)row.ToString(), missing);
            switch (Formattype)
            {
                case "Date":
                    Crange1.NumberFormat = "d-mmm-yyyy";
                    Crange1.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                    break;
                case "Number":
                    Crange1.NumberFormat = "0";
                    Crange1.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion



    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running in 64bit mode?

Comment: @JoeC Yes my office is 64 bit

Comment: I used to have problems because the office drivers for 64 bit either didnt exist or were not working correctly.  When you run is successfully in visual studio (locally) can you check the project properties and see if use64bit runtime is false?  If so, doing the same in the job could solve the issue.  I am guessing you mean a sql agent job?  If so are you using SSISDB or TSQL or another method to launch the package?

Comment: @JoeC I tried that the job still runs interactively both locally and on server but it fails when I run it through a job by ssms. I have the 32 bit execution enabled in the job step

Comment: When you say run in the server how do you mean?  In visual studio?  Is the package deployed and you launch with tsql or dtexec?  You say it fails when you say run a job in ssms. Do you mean SQL agent job?  If so are you using a proxy?  It may be a permissions issue.